# Google Analytics Android App: Real Time Data and Manual Dispatch

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

I just implemented Google Analytics v3 into my android app and have some small qtns. I'm familiar with Google Analytics for webpages but not apps.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/dispatch

Q1: How does real time data work when the default dispatch period is half an hour? Also I'm assuming that 30 mins is only for when the app is running, right? By my experience, the real time data only shows one screenview which corresponds to me opening the app. All subsequent screenviews are not shown in real time UNTIL I close the app and re-open. It's almost like this triggers the dispatch to occur causing all the queued data to get dispatched. Is this normal behaviour?

This is not ideal for my app since it will probably be only used for 5 mins at a time. I've been reading up on manual dispatches, which leads me to my next question...

Q2: Is it a bad idea to turn off the periodic dispatch and make my app manually dispatch the data everytime a screenview takes place? I mean periodic dispatch is probably employed so that the data can be batch-sent to the server all at once so that communication with the server isn't as frequent right? Using manual dispatches is the only way I can imagine that the real time data would be accurate...I'm interested in the real time data so this is quite important for me although I don't want to be doing frequent dispatches if it is going to be too intensive for my app...what do you think?

Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: Did you get an answer to Q1?